# Alternating tensors: Difference between $Alt$ and $\frac{1}{k!} Alt$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

From Dummit Foote Chapter 11.5: pages [452](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umVgW.png) and [453](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhkHH.png). I believe I was able to reprove these with $Alt$ instead of $\frac{1}{k!} Alt$. Maybe I made a mistake.

What's the difference between $Alt$ and $\frac{1}{k!} Alt$? Is it perhaps merely a conventional thing like the $a_0$ vs $\frac{a_0}{2}$ in Fourier series?

Comment: If you have a $k$-tensor $z$ which is already alternant, then it would be desirable (depending on the context) to have $\operatorname{Alt}(z)=z$. This can be done if we put $1/k!\operatorname{Alt}$ instead of $\operatorname{Alt}$. That's all I know!

Comment: $\frac{1}{k!}$ may be undefined in $R$

Comment: @Magdiragdag Yeah, but what if $k!$ is already a unit in $R$?

Comment: @EBO So it's just a conventional thing like with Fourier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of Alt as a projection map that maps any given covariant k-tensor to an alternating covariant k-tensor.

If $\alpha$ is already an alternating covariant k-tensor, then it looks elegant if Alt $\alpha = \alpha$ ( That is Alt should map alternating covariant k-tensors to themselves)

However, according to the  definition of Alternation in Dumme and Foote, Alt $\alpha = (k!)\alpha $.

So, we introduce a new projection map, $\frac{1}{k!} Alt $, that naturally maps alternating covariant k-tensors to alternating covariant k-tensors (themselves).

That is $ \frac{1}{k!}$ Alt $\alpha=\alpha $.

So $ \frac{1}{k!}$ can be thought of as a normalization for elegance. It is elegant to define an map (operator) that takes alternating covariant k-tensors to themselves, and non-alternating covariant k-tensors to alternating covariant k-tensors.

Comment: I noticed '$ \frac{1}{k!}$ Alt $\alpha=\alpha $' in the book. So it's just a conventional thing like with Fourier?

Comment: Yes it is conventional. $\frac{1}{k!}Alt $ is a more elegant convention because it does not affect alternating tensors.

Comment: Thanks, sathishT.